# .checked not identifying if a radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button, checked

I have some radio buttons on a page, and I need to just identify which one was checked in my JS, based on ID. I'm not sure why this isn't working. Each time, I get the "nothing checked" message in my console. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="aud1">elephant</input>
<input type="radio" id="aud2">prairie dog</input>
<input type="radio" id="aud3">tiger</input>
```

JS:

```
var aud;
if (document.getElementById('aud1').checked) {
  var aud = document.getElementById('file1');
}else if(document.getElementById('aud2').checked) {
 var aud = document.getElementById('file2');
}else if (document.getElementById('aud3').checked){
 var aud = document.getElementById('file3');
}
else console.log('nothing checked');
```

Comment: But nothing is checked when the page loads. Is this called from another function?

Answer (score 0):

See below. I've added a button to your code that you can click after you have some checked.

Initially, when the page loads, there is nothing clicked. Your JS is ran as soon as the page is built there which is why you were seeing the nothing clicked.

```js
document.getElementById('check-radios').onclick = function() {
  var aud;
  if (document.getElementById('aud1').checked) {
    var aud = document.getElementById('file1');
    console.log('aud1 checked');
  } 
  else if (document.getElementById('aud2').checked) {
    var aud = document.getElementById('file2');
    console.log('aud2 checked');
  } 
  else if (document.getElementById('aud3').checked) {
    var aud = document.getElementById('file3');
    console.log('aud3 checked');
  } 
  else console.log('nothing checked');
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="aud1">elephant</input>
<input type="radio" id="aud2">prairie dog</input>
<input type="radio" id="aud3">tiger</input>

<button id="check-radios">Check for clicked</button>
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Of course. I can't believe I missed that!!! Thank you for pointing out the obvious to me!

Comment: No problem, if this helps please accept as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

do you explicitly need this code? why not use a single class, and have the filename/desc as a custom attribute like so:

```
    <input type="radio" name="animals" class="order" data-animal="elephant" />elephant
    <input type="radio" name="animals" class="order" data-animal="zebra" />zebra
    <input type="radio" name="animals" class="order" data-animal="lion" />lion


<script>
    $(".order").click(function () {
    var choice = this.getAttribute("data-animal");

    alert(choice);
    /* console.log(choice); */
})
</script>
```

That way you dont have to manually keep adding more code, u can just add the html at the top using the same class and a different attribute value... much easier to maintain -

Also since you had an elseif i added a name to group them as individual radios as I presume you intended?

```
 <input type="radio" name="animals" class="order" checked data-animal="zebra">zebra
```

bear in mind there is no closing tag for input tags - just /> at the end instead of >

Comment: Thanks-- yeah, I wanted to refactor this so it isn't as brittle. The issue is that I need to set a variable to a specific audio file. I guess I could just name the variables after each custom attribute.

Comment: yes that wd work - make sure your file names are url friendly if you intend using them on the site.. and follow filename conventions for actual files.